# I'm creating a Windows Forms application, how can I ask the user to enter name in block letters?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have started a Windows Forms application. When a registration form runs, it should ask the user to enter his name in block letters, any text box should not be left NULL, and how to create a text which should be alpha numeric?

Comment: Just those 3 things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set the textbox to be all uppercased you can run this:

```
textBox.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper;
```

To make it non-null-able, you would need to check if there is text on it on the button press event. Like this:

```
if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox.Text))
{
   MessageBox.Show("You need to input your name.");
}
```

Remember to change `textBox` to your textbox name.